# How to send push notification from angular 6 project to android app

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, firebase, push-notification

I have an android app in which I send push notification using firebase admin sdk with nodejs.

I was able to send notification from the nodejs raw script when I ran the script.

[image]

However, I just built an admin dashboard for sending notification to the app with angular 6 but don't know how to integrate the nodejs script with the new angular app so that I can send notification from the angular app by just a click.

I'd also encourage new ideas on how best to to this.
attached is a screenshot from the nodejs admin script

Answer (score 1):

Setup your node to behave as API server, using [Express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express) for example.

Wrap your script as Express module (named `send-message.js`), basically just make that a function that you export:

```
const sendMessage = (...params) => {
   //your send message logic, I would do copy paste of your code here however it is an image
}

module.exports = sendMessage;
```

Well and then setup API route that calls the script:

```
var express = require('express')
var sendMessage = require('./send-message')
var app = express()

app.get('/send-message', function (req, res) {
  sendMessage(....);
  res.status(200).end();
})

app.listen(3000)
```

And finally in Angular use `HttpClient` to call the API.

Comment: Thank you @Pes for the insight, however I encountered numerous errors due to the use of the require statement in the file

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved the problem by using [firebase cloud functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/).

1. First I set up cloud functions on firebase with this [guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started)
2. Then I created a cloud function named sendNotification() which is triggered each time new objects are inserted to the firebase realtime database.
3. Then I placed my existing notification code inside sendNotification() function
4. Deployed the function to my firebase console
5. Then hurray, the notification was sent to my device after some db triggers

`

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();


//This functions listens to the node '/Food menu/date/Food' for new insert and sends notification to a client
exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref('/Food menu/date/Food')
.onCreate((snapshot, context) => {

  //place your client app registration token here, this is created when a user first opens the app and it is stored in the db. 
  //You could also retrieve the token from the db but in this case it is hard coded
  var registrationToken = "{my-registration-token}";

  //This is the payload for notification

  var payload = {
    data: {
      'title': 'Tomorrow\'s Menu',
      'message': 'Hello, kindly check the menu available for today',
      'is_background': 'true',
      'image': 'http://www.allwhitebackground.com/images/3/3430.jpg',
      'timestamp': '234'
    }
  };

  // Send a message to the device corresponding to the provided
  // registration token.
  admin.messaging().sendToDevice(registrationToken, payload)
    .then((response) => {
      // Response is a message ID string.
      console.log('Successfully sent message:', response);

      //return a promise here since this function is asynchronous
      return "Yes";
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log('Error sending message:', error);
    });

  //return snapshot.ref.parent.child('uppercaseFood').set(uppercase);
});
```

`

After this, you run `firebase deploy --only functions`to deploy the cloud function

Read this [guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started) for more info on cloud functions